# Expect Programming: How to expect exactly what is prompted?

Tags: java, linux, expect

I am asking this question particularly for an `Expect` implementation in `Java`. However, I would like to know general suggestions as well.

**In Expect programming, is it possible to expect exactly what is prompted after spawning a new process?**

For example, instead of expecting some pattern or a fixed string, isn't it better to just expect what is prompted. I feel this should be really helpful at times(especially when there's no conditional sending).

Consider the [sample java code](https://nikunjp.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/remote-ssh-using-jsch-with-expect4j/) here that uses `JSch` and `Expect4j` java libraries to do ssh and execute list of commands(`ls`,`pwd`,`mkdir testdir`) on the remote machine.

My question here is why is it necessary to specify a pattern for the prompt? Is it not possible it to get the exact prompt from `Channel` itself and expect it?

Comment: Can you clarify this with an example?

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry, can't help - just here for the Java tag.

Answer (score 0):

I've programmed in "expect" and in "java".

I think you misunderstand what "expect" basically does.  It doesn't look for exact items prompted after spawning a new process.

An expect program basically consists of:

1. Something that reads the terminal
2. A set of patterns (typically regular expressions), coupled to a blocks of code.

So, when a new process is spawned, there's a loop that looks something like this

```
while (terminal.hasMoreText()) {
  buffered_text += terminal.readInput();
  for (Pattern pattern : patterns) {
     if (pattern.matches(buffered_text)) {
        String match = pattern.getMatch(buffered_text);
        bufferedText.removeAllTextBefore(match);
        bufferedText.removeText(match);
        pattern.executeBlock();
     }
  }
}
```

Of course, this is a massive generalization.  But it is close enough to illustrate that expect itself doesn't "exactly expect" anything after launching a process.  The program provided to the expect interpreter (which primarily consists of patterns and blocks of code to execute when the patterns match) contains the items which the interpreter's loop will use to match the process's output.

This is why you see some pretty odd expect scripts.  For example, nearly everyone "expects" "ogin:" instead of "Login:" because there's little consistency on whether the login prompt is upper or lower case.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. My question is why shouldn't `what is read  from terminal` be one among the `set of patterns`.

Comment: @jnanthak "what is read from the terminal" is the thing your patterns should match against.  Many things printed to the terminal contain text that is relatively stable and text that is reliably different.  A pattern like "ogin:" matches "Login:", "login:" and "Warning we prosecute unauthorized entry, login:" as well as, "Welcome, today's date is 7/11\nlogin:"  The power of the expect language is to skip over the exact details, looking for the important parts to respond to.

Comment: @jnanthak Exact matching isn't a bad idea, but when the input varies, it is impossible to write the correct pattern to exactly match until after the program is running and has received the input into its buffer.  That means you'd have a programming language that required you to program it as it was running based on the input as it was receiving it.  In such a scenario, the programming language becomes the unnecessary portion, and you might as well type the input directly into the terminal yourself (instead of having a program type it in for you).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to expect anything. You're free to just send commands immediately and indiscriminately.

It's considered good practice to only reply to specific prompts so that you don't accidentally ruin something by saying the wrong thing at the wrong time, but you're entirely free to ignore this.

The main consideration is that while your normal flow might be:

```
$ create-backup
$ mkdir latest
$ mv backup.tar.gz latest
```

With no expectations and just blindly writing input, you can end up with this:

```
$ create-backup
Disk full, cleanup started...
Largest file: precious-family-memories.tar (510MB)
 [R]emove, [S]ave, [A]bort
Invalid input: m
Invalid input: k
Invalid input: d
Invalid input: i
Removing file...
$  latest
latest: command not found
$ mv backup.tar.gz latest
```

whereas a program that expects `$` before continuing would just wait and eventually realize that things are not going according to plan.

A few commands are sensitive to timing (e.g. telnet), but other than that you can send commands whenever you want, with or without waiting for anything at all.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Expecting nothing and sending everything could be very dangerous. What am trying to ask is, is it possible to capture the `$` from the new shell once it is spawned and use it for expect. This should make the expect script work independent of the prompt.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this because there is no way to generally recognize a shell command prompt. It can be customized to use any characters, and fancy colorful prompts often are. You'd be better off running a single composite command like `cd foo && ls && pwd` that itself takes care of proper sequencing